# How does docker treat file paths?

Tags: python, docker

When attaching to a running docker container, I've noticed that the file paths (in bash) are that of my local machine.   For instance, my user name is part of the file path etc.

How do I ascertain the appropriate file path to put in my python script and dockerfile?  (both of which have been included in an image). Right now my local file path works but I'm not sure why I should define my WORKDIR as my local file path if it's a brand new image.

Answer (score 0):

When you attach yourself to a docker container, you are logging onto a container which is built from a docker image. It has nothing to do with your host OS. For example if you use UBUNTU base image, then the paths will obviously be different from Red hat base image.

That said, you can mount your local file paths as a volume or bind mount. This comes into picture if you want some part of the docker container file system to be persisted between container restarts.
If you want to include python scripts, you add it by using a DockerFile and building it. Example below

```
FROM tomcat
LABEL maintainer="xxx"

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get -y install openssh-server && \  

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package.json .
RUN npm install
EXPOSE 4000   
CMD [ “npm”, “start” ]
```

Docker uses layering system. So make sure you put in the parts of your code that changes often at the bottom of the dockerfile so that you can leverage this. From the above example you can see that I copy in the python file towards the end and I am basing my image on the tomcat image.

WORKDIR sets the working directory and is useful if you are running a script via Entyrpoint, CMD etc. Actually it is the same as `cd /usr/src/app && np npm install` but people prefer `workdir` for readability. Also, It has nothing to do with a brand new image thing that you mentioned above.

Hope you get the big picture. Let me know if you have any questions